# how can i convert String to font

Tags: c#, winforms

I already save à font to à file and now I would like to convert string to Font.

```
   Font currFont = FontDialog.Font;
  TextWriter MyData = 
  new.StreamWriter(ClData.FileFontTitlePath);
  Mydata.WriteLine(currFont);
  Mydata. Close();
```

Comment: what do mean save font family or size? you only want to save that in 2 vaiable?

Comment: I manage to save it to à file, then now I want to convert à string(from à file) to à Font.

Comment: That wouldn't be of type `FontDialog` - that would be of type `Font`. What did you save to a file? Why isn't that in your question?

Comment: ok then tell to use some information about your saved data in file, in witch format?

Comment: My client want me to save font to à file à retrieve it on another file

Comment: then you want to save the font setting in a file and then open the file in another system and use it?